# jquery - passing css from one element to another

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if it is possible to replace lets say a div with a span (which i can do) but pass on all the declared css from that element to the new?

regards,

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: You should just define all CSS for the `div` with `.myClass { /* stuff here */ }`, and then replace `<div class="myClass">` with `<span class="myClass">`. Problem solved..

Comment: Why do you even need to do this, anyway?

Comment: what if the CSS changes after the page loads, but not related to its class?

Answer (score 3):

If you add the classes,id and style attribute it should be fine..

```
var div = $('yourdivid');
var span = $('<span>',{
        id:div.attr('id'),
        html:div.html(), 
        class:div.attr('class'), 
        style:div.attr('style')
    });
div.replaceWith(span);
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/KQdGX/

---

Be aware though that styles that are applied through CSS rules that target the tag `div` will not be reproduced..

Comment: this will not work. div { foo:bar; } will not get passed to the new span that it is being replaced with. I was hoping for something along the lines of var passCss = $(oldEl).css();

Comment: @Phil, also what about the case where there is also a rule of `span {foo:bar!important;}`. Should the `span` rule apply or the `div` one ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.style` of the DOM element? It's an object which contains members such as width and backgroundColor.

```
document.getElementById("id").style.property="value"
```

---

Or use this code 
Made by [Dakota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362042/dakota)

Warning: This code generates a lot of output, and should be used sparingly. It not only copies all standard CSS properties, but also all vendor CSS properties for that browser.

jquery.getStyleObject.js:

```
/*
 * getStyleObject Plugin for jQuery JavaScript Library
 * From: http://upshots.org/?p=112
 *
 * Copyright: Unknown, see source link
 * Plugin version by Dakota Schneider (http://hackthetruth.org)
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            }
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i=0;i<style.length;i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            }
            return returns;
        }
        if(dom.currentStyle){
            style = dom.currentStyle;
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            }
            return returns;
        }
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Basic usage is pretty simple:

```
var style = $("#original").getStyleObject; // copy all computed CSS properties
$("#original").clone() // clone the object
    .parent() // select it's parent
    .appendTo() // append the cloned object to the parent, after the original
                // (though this could really be anywhere and ought to be somewhere
                // else to show that the styles aren't just inherited again
    .css(style); // apply cloned styles
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, i tweaked n got this working :
`document.getElementById("destinationid").style.height = document.getElementById('sourceid').offsetHeight+"px"`