# replaceWith() without deleting the original element

Tags: jquery

Is there a jQuery function similar to `replaceWith()` to replace an element with a new element, without destroying the original element (simply hiding it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do :

```
<button>replace</button>
<div class="toReplace">your first content</div >
<div class="toReplace" style="display: none">your second content</div >
```

then in js :

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("toReplace").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `hide`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/hide)]</sup>* and `after`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/after)]</sup>*:

```
$('#oldElem').hide().after($('#newElem'));
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
$(this).before("this is what I'm inserting").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Toggling visibility may work in some cases, but the preferred method would be to clone the original element. For example:

```
var clone = $('#elementOne');
$('#elementToBeReplaced').replaceWith(clone);
```

This is especially useful when managing form inputs as the DOM doesn't care if the element is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the element after or before it and then hide the element itself. Try this

```
$("element").hide().after($("newElement"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it with css just call [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) before [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like:

```
$('#theolddiv').hide().after('$(<div>The new div</div>'));
```

If you want to completely remove it from the DOM, not just hide it with css, but want to be able to re-insert it later, maybe somewhere else in the DOM even, then store it in a variable like:

```
var $x = $('#theolddiv');
$x.replaceWith('<div>The new div</div>');
// Do stuff here, you can put $x back in the DOM if you want.
```

That actually makes a copy of the Object, but it's good enough :)