# How to change output HTML tag <b></b> to <strong></strong>?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to replace `<b></b>` tag with `<strong></strong>` tag to a specific div?

ex:

```
<div id="aaa">hello<b>wow</b>!</div>
```

using javascript to replace with

```
<div id="aaa">hello<strong>wow</strong>!</div>
```

please help! thanks in advance.

[image]

***** Why I'm try to do is change the output HTML code `<b></b>` to `<strong></strong>` , in order to get W3C validation. Can I do that? **

**Or Is there any solution that can use ASP.NET+C# to do that?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: Just out of interest, why? `<strong>` and `<b>` do the same thing, other than the former is interpreted by screenreaders.

Comment: @Samich The OP didn't specify jQuery...

Comment: Why I'm doing this is because of W3C.

Comment: @Šime Vidas maybe OP don't know yet jQuery, but it's  a good chance to learn it

Comment: @JamWaffles, both `<b>` and `<strong>` render the same in a browser **by default**, but `<strong>` provides more meaning (strong emphasis), whereas `<b>` is simply a visual styling. A subtle difference, but sometimes an important one.

Comment: **Note**: the W3C validator will not execute your JavaScript so if you're doing this just to validate your document, then keep in mind that the validator will only see the original source, not the modified DOM.

Comment: or you can do this using server-side language to write the HTML/CSS of your page.

Comment: In the image you posted, your script is running before the document is loaded. (That is, `<div id="test">` doesn't exist yet.) You need to put the script after the content you want to modify (just before the closing `</body>` tag will do. There are other ways to fix it, but this is the simplest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var root, elems;

root = document.getElementById( 'test' );
elems = root.getElementsByTagName( 'b' );

toArray( elems ).forEach( function ( elem ) {
    var newElem = document.createElement( 'strong' );
    newElem.textContent = elem.textContent;
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild( newElem, elem );    
});
```

where `toArray` is your preferred array-like to array converter function. I use this one:

```
function toArray( arrayLike ) { return [].slice.call( arrayLike ); }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mJSyH/3/

*Note: this code doesn't work in IE8.*

Comment: Why doesn't it work in IE? Nice answer nevertheless, learned a thing or two :)

Comment: `forEach` is new in JS, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @x3ro IE8 doesn't implement `forEach` and `textContent`. One could use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`, and `forEach` can easily be manually implemented in IE8, so with some additional effort, this can work in IE8, too.

Comment: can I change the output HTML code  `<b></b> ` to  `<strong></strong> `?

Comment: @user In the browsers (where JavaScript is executed), there is no "output HTML". The HTML source code is used as an input to create the DOM tree. If you need this change to be made on the HTML source code (before sending it to the browsers), you'll need to do it on the server...

Answer (score 5):

You can grab all `<b>` elements under a certain element, move all child nodes to a new `<strong>` element, and then replace the `<b>` with the `<strong>`.

```
<div id="aaa">hello<b>wow</b><b>2</b><b>3</b>!</div>

<script>
  var container = document.getElementById("aaa")
  var find = container.getElementsByTagName("b");
  var bold, strong;

  while (bold = find[0]) {
    strong = document.createElement("strong");

    while (bold.firstChild) {
      strong.appendChild(bold.firstChild);
    }

    bold.parentNode.replaceChild(strong, bold);
  }
</script>
```

The reason you can set `bold = find[0]` every time is that as the `<b>` elements are removed from the document, they are also removed from the `NodeList` `find`.

See the latest version at http://jsbin.com/eqikaj/13/edit.

Comment: +1 This is a good way to do it. You could even get rid of the `i`, and do a `while (bold = find[0]) {` since your `find` list will update with each removal.

Comment: Great point, @Patrick. Those dynamic `NodeList`s will get you every time. Updating the solution now.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't even thinking about the fact that you were walking forward through the updating list. Still, I'd personally keep it as a NodeList and [just assign to `find[0]`](http://jsbin.com/eqikaj/10/edit) without updating the index. That'll get you through the list without any skips, it'll be much faster, and more browser compatible since you can't place a NodeList (or any Host Object) as the *thisArg* of `.slice()` in IE8 or lower.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can find all `b` tags in scope of your parent `div` container element and then replace each of them with `strong` and copy inner text of the source tag:

```
$('#aaa b').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('<strong>' + this.html() + '</strong>');
});
```

Comment: not sure if feasible answer, since question doesn't say jquery, it says javascript.

Comment: I mentioned in the first sentence that is using jQuery.

Comment: If for some reason you have event handlers attached to anything inside of a `<b>` element, they will be lost with the use of `this.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can simply go like this:

```
$('b').replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<strong>').html($(this).html());
});
```

Just download or include the jQuery library somehow, and you can use the snippet. 
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: `.html` may be a better choice if the tag contains other tags, like: `<b>With <em>emphasis</em></b>`

Comment: I thought of that too, I just went to check the documentation. Just in case. :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using **regular expressions:**

```
var e = document.getElementById("aaa");
e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/<b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>/ig, '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

perhaps is not more fast that the versions  above.
but the perfomace difference is very little(irrelevant  in real applications). 
Use  whichever you think best

**note:** you don't need use a function as `toArray`, you can do this:

```
Array.forEach(elems, function() {  ... })
```