# Change the type of element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I know the ID of an element, is it possible to change the type of HTML tag that it has?

For example if you have `<p id="p">Lots and lots of text here.</p>`, is it possible to change it to `<span id="p">....`?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: @Vikk - Thanks, I wasn't able to find the answer on here earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `replaceWith` method to do this. You'll need to rebuild the attributes for the replacement though.

```
$('#p').replaceWith(function(){
   return '<span>' + $(this).contents().text() + '</span>';
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bs9Pe/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var a = $('#p').text();
$('#p').replaceWith('<span id="#p">' + a + '</span>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teBuN/

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);
var new = document.createElement("span");
new.id = el.id;
[].forEach.call(el.childNodes, function (node) {
  new.appendChild(node);
});
el.parentNode.replaceChild(new, el);
```

Now, a good question, is why. Why would you want to change the html element?

Surely you choose the most semantic element for this piece of data, why would another element be a better choice?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").replaceWith(....) .............
```

Comment: I think David is looking for $("#p").replaceWith(...) to replace one particular element in the DOM with the id of "p", versus replacing all paragraph tags with the same new content.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - This did get me on the right path though, as I did not know of the existence of `replaceWith()`. Thanks.

Comment: so select the answer who helped you.