# Use jquery to convert divs into spans

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to alter the HTML output of a widget I have no control over.  Basically the issue is that the widget outputs HTML that uses divs inside of a p which is not valid..

```
<div class="widget_output">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
            </p>
       </li>
       <li>
            <p>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
                <div>This is a random item</div>
            </p>
        </li>
</div>
```

My idea is to change the divs into spans which are inline elements, the HTML should then be valid.  I have been looking at jquery to try and select the class and then convert these divs into spans.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or a tutorial of someone achieving something similar?

Comment: Why not change from `display: block` to `display: inline`? This way you don't break any existing code with the widget that relies on them being divs.

Comment: You can't reliably change the "html" with jQuery because it has been already parsed into DOM. And what kind of result you get depends on the browser, chrome creates 2 `p` elements with `div` as siblings. Please create valid html in the first place.

Comment: If I could control the HTML in the first place then this wouldn't be an issue.  Ass I explicitly mentioned in my original question, I have not control over the widgets HTML ouput.

Comment: @fightstarr20 It depends on how you are retrieving the widget's html. You could modify its html before it's parsed.

Comment: The widgets HTML is sent by an API so as far as I can see I have no control over it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need jQuery for that, you can simply use regular expression to replace `<div>` tags with `<span>` tags. Try this:

```
var widgetHTML = $('div.widget_output').html();
    widgetHTML = widgetHTML
       .replace(/<div>/g, '<span>')
       .replace(/<\/div>/g, '</span>');
$('div.widget_output').html(widgetHTML);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/daYL4/3/

Comment: I'm not sure why I went off thinking I would need to use jQuery, this solution seems a lot simpler.  I am doing this within a wordpress site and your solution isn't working currently.  I think it is just the way I have implemented it inside my functions file

Comment: You have to run the above code once your widget is loaded. Let me know if you get any errors?

Comment: I think Im on the right lines, I am trying to implement it like this inside of my functions.php http://pastebin.com/k9Ax8F6b

Comment: Did you see any error in the console? Have you checked what you get in `widgetHTML` variable inside `my_custom_js()` function?

Comment: I am getting the white screen of death currently so I am assuming there is something amiss with my code implementation as in a missing ; or similar?

Comment: without calling `my_custom_js()` function, do you get the same white screen of death?

Comment: Yep, still get it with the call removed

Comment: This won't work because the regular expression looks for <div> and your html code has <div class="widget_output">.  If you change the third line to this: `.replace(/<div/g, '<span')` it should work

Answer (score 19):

Just stuck a JSFiddle together:

http://jsfiddle.net/daYL4/3/

```
$(".widget_output div").replaceWith(function() { 
    return "<span>" + this.innerHTML + "</span>"; 
});
```

Seems to work better than my original suggestion.
​
But take a look at the answers to this related question, as they cover some good points:

[Use jQuery to change an HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag)

Comment: Am I missing something or does the JSFiddle result still have DIVS where I would expect to be seeing SPANS?

Comment: Erm, for some reason my changes didn't save... updated it now! http://jsfiddle.net/daYL4/3/

Comment: I have tried it again but am still not seeing the DIVS as SPANS?

Comment: It's definitely working now. You can see that they're displaying inline though, right (i.e. one after each other, rather than on different lines). Make sure you're "inspecting" the element, rather than "viewing source", as JQuery cannot modify the rendered HTML, just the in memory HTML.

Comment: But if jQuery cannot modify the rendered HTML then surely your solution would not have any effect on the validation?

Comment: JQuery does not modify the physical HTML document - only the server side of a HTTP request can do that. A HTML document is rendered by a browser, then JQuery (or any other client side script) will modify the browser's "in memory" version of the document (which is referred to as a DOM - Document Object Model). It's incidental how all that works, however, as if you use "Inspect Element" in any browser, rather than view source, you will see the browser's DOM version... which shows any of your scripted changes.