# How to replace a tag with another and keep attributes using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, replacewith

How to replace `<ins>` tag with `<del>` tag and keep attributes of it in javascript or jquery? like the following

```
<ins data-author="auth1" data-ins-username="user1">auth1 text</ins>
<!-- After -->
<del data-author="auth1" data-ins-username="user1">auth1 text</del>
```

I found similar question with answer but it doesn't keep attributes.

Comment: is this changing of tag? unwrap and move is not every clear for this matter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11707679/1719752

Comment: A great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20469901/3432932

Comment: @Vaidas: will not retain attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to replacing a tag with another. In function get `outerHTML` of element and replace tag name with another.

```
$("ins").replaceWith(function(){
    return this.outerHTML.replace("<ins", "<del").replace("</ins", "</del")
});
```

```js
$("ins").replaceWith(function(){
    return this.outerHTML.replace("<ins", "<del").replace("</ins", "</del")
});
console.log($("del")[0].outerHTML);
```

```css
del { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ins data-author="auth1" data-ins-username="user1">auth1 text</ins>
```