# replace specific tag name javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know if we can change tag name in a tag rather than its content. I have this content

```
<wns id="93" onclick="wish(id)">...</wns>
```

In the `wish` function I want to change it to

```
<lmn id="93" onclick="wish(id)">...</lmn>
```

I tried this way:

```
document.getElementById("99").innerHTML = document.getElementById("99").replace(/wns/g,"lmn");
```

but it does not work.

Please note that I just want to alter that specific tag with specific id rather than every `wns` tag.

Comment: First of all, those tagnames are not valid HTML, and no, you can't change a tagname in HTML (you can however replace it).

Comment: Perhaps this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var element = document.getElementById("93");
element.outerHTML = element.outerHTML.replace(/wns/g,"lmn");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s98J5/)

Comment: How's the support for `outerHTML` in the wild these days?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - actually checked this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) myself, and does'nt seem that bad!

Comment: That's cool. Making the round-trip through markup will remove any event handlers on the descendant elements, though, which is less than ideal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yeah, it's the easy way for browsers that support it, but you loose everything that's not explicitly set in the markup, like event handlers on descending elements!

Comment: I checked it in chrome n firefox,
it does work..
thanks a million  :)

Comment: Amazing. I'd always thought `outerHTML` was a getter only, and couldn't be set. Revelatory!

Comment: Yeah but what if you have "wns" in the innerhtml of the tag?

Comment: @NickManning - The OP didn't, but then you could do something like `.replace(/<wns(.*?)/g,"<lmn$1")`

Comment: I'd *at least* use word boundary markers on the replacement, and a big old caveat that this *replaces* the element would also be a good idea. :-)

Comment: Nice, but not ideal, this changes every occurrence of the string `wms` throughout the HTML.

Comment: It not reaally works, it triggers. Try to change an attribute at the same time. It will not be applied. This is because outerHTML is a snapshot from `getElementById`. After the script has processed the browser will trigger a rerendering and after that you will be able to access it again with it's new tagname, so it depends if this solutions fits for you or not, for me it doesn't.

Comment: If you have `wns` in content, it will be replaced. That's not funny.

Comment: Just use the full regex: `Element.outerHTML = Element.outerHTML.replace(/^<wms(.*)wms>$/, "<lmn$1lmn>")`

Answer (score 35):

You can't change the tag name of an existing DOM element; instead, you have to create a replacement and then insert it where the element was.

The basics of this are to move the child nodes into the replacement and similarly to copy the attributes. So for instance:

```
var wns = document.getElementById("93");
var lmn = document.createElement("lmn");
var index;

// Copy the children
while (wns.firstChild) {
    lmn.appendChild(wns.firstChild); // *Moves* the child
}

// Copy the attributes
for (index = wns.attributes.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    lmn.attributes.setNamedItem(wns.attributes[index].cloneNode());
}

// Replace it
wns.parentNode.replaceChild(lmn, wns);
```

**Live Example:** *(I used `div` and `p` rather than `wns` and `lmn`, and styled them via a stylesheet with borders so you can see the change)*

```js
document.getElementById("theSpan").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Span clicked");
}, false);

document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var wns = document.getElementById("target");
  var lmn = document.createElement("p");
  var index;

  // Copy the children
  while (wns.firstChild) {
    lmn.appendChild(wns.firstChild); // *Moves* the child
  }

  // Copy the attributes
  for (index = wns.attributes.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    lmn.attributes.setNamedItem(wns.attributes[index].cloneNode());
  }

  // Insert it
  wns.parentNode.replaceChild(lmn, wns);
}, false);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" foo="bar" onclick="alert('hi there')">
  Content before
  <span id="theSpan">span in the middle</span>
  Content after
</div>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Click Me">
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Hug/d245b53b6195b9596c00659cb17cda6c) for a reusable function.

---

Side note: I would avoid using `id` values that are all digits. Although they're valid in HTML (as of HTML5), they're invalid in CSS and thus you can't style those elements, or use libraries like jQuery that use CSS selectors to interact with them.

Comment: Actually you **can**! Dirty example: `tag.outerHTML = "<" + newName + ">" + tag.innerHTML + "</" + newName + ">";`

Comment: @Bitterblue: Nope. :-) That creates a *new* element and swaps it in for the old one. And just like other ways you do that, you lose event handlers, you lose expandos, any outstanding references to the object point to the *old* element, etc. Example: http://jsbin.com/kucuf/1 In the normal case, your code above is effectively the same as `var newElement = document.createElement(newName); newElement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML; element.parentNode.replaceChild(element, newElement);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this seems like the best answer, but why didn't you just use replaceChild instead of the last insert and remove methods?

Comment: `function changeTag(el, newTagName = "div") { var newEl = document.createElement(newTagName); [...el.children].forEach(o => newEl.appendChild(o)); [...el.attributes].forEach(o => newEl.attributes.setNamedItem(o.cloneNode())); el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el); return newEl; }`

Comment: `wns.parentNode.replaceChild(lmn, wns)` == `wns.replaceWith(lmn)`. maybe its faster with `wns.style.display = "none"` to avoid onscreen repaints on `lmn.appendChild(wns.firstChild)`

Comment: @milahu - Re `replaceWith`, indeed yes. It didn't exist in 2013. :-) I don't think there's any need for the `display: none` thing, though? The code above is synchronous, so as I understand it no repaints will occur while that code is running (reflows, yes, but no repaints).

Answer (score 9):

There are several problems with your code:

1. HTML element IDs must start with an alphabetic character.
2. `document.getElementById("99").replace(/wns/g,"lmn")` is effectively running a replace command on an element. Replace is a string method so this causes an error.
3. You're trying to assign this result to `document.getElementById("99").innerHTML`, which is the HTML *inside* the element (the tags, attributes and all are part of the `outerHTML`).
4. You can't change an element's tagname dynamically, since it fundamentally changes it's nature. Imagine changing a `textarea` to a `select`… There are so many attributes that are exclusive to one, illegal in the other: the system cannot work!

What you can do though, is create a new element, and give it all the properties of the old element, then replace it:

```
<wns id="e93" onclick="wish(id)">
    ...
</wns>
```

Using the following script:

```
// Grab the original element
var original    = document.getElementById('e93');
// Create a replacement tag of the desired type
var replacement = document.createElement('lmn');

// Grab all of the original's attributes, and pass them to the replacement
for(var i = 0, l = original.attributes.length; i < l; ++i){
    var nodeName  = original.attributes.item(i).nodeName;
    var nodeValue = original.attributes.item(i).nodeValue;

    replacement.setAttribute(nodeName, nodeValue);
}

// Persist contents
replacement.innerHTML = original.innerHTML;

// Switch!
original.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, original);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/barney/kDjuf/

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the whole tag using jQuery

```
var element = $('#99');
element.replaceWith($(`<lmn id="${element.attr('id')}">${element.html()}</lmn>`));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.example')].forEach(div => {
  div.outerHTML =
  div.outerHTML
    .replace(/<div/g, '<span')
    .replace(/<\/div>/g, '</span>')
})
```

```html
<div class="example">Hello,</div>
<div class="example">world!</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript or jQuery.

We can delete the DOM Element(tag in this case) and recreate using .html or .append menthods in jQuery.

```
$("#div-name").html("<mytag>Content here</mytag>");
```

OR

```
$("<mytag>Content here</mytag>").appendTo("#div-name");
```