# How to change DOM element to object element?

Tags: javascript, dom

Does anyone know how to change a *DOM* element to an object, and change the object back to *DOM* element?

I want to convert a DOM element to an object and convert it to JSON using `JSON.stringify`.

Anyone know how to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace specific tag name javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086677/replace-specific-tag-name-javascript)

Comment: can you please give an example about what problem are u facing??

Comment: What?! Everything in the DOM is an `Element` , which is automatically an `Object`. If you dont believe me enter `new Element instanceof Object` ...

Comment: Hi Jonas w and Apoorv , i want convert a dom element to an object and convert to json by json.stringify