# Modify TagName of html sourcecode using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I need to modify TagName of html sourcecode using selenium in python.
For example:

how to edit span in div:

```
  <span class="main-menu">
```

in this:

```
  <div class="main-menu">
```

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Why do you want to change the tag in the source code? As the change that you are doing is on the client side and the moment you refresh/reload the page the changes will be lost.

Comment: I know but i need to do this, could you explain me?

Comment: What you can do is https://stackoverflow.com/a/15086792/8375783