# How to convert ul to option

Tags: jquery

How can I convert an unordered list:

```
<ul class="sizeSelect dropdown-menu">
    <li value="112">
        <a onclick="setDropdownText(112);">30x30 30" Waist 30" Leg</a>
    </li>
    <li value="51">
        <a onclick="setDropdownText(51);">30x32 30" Waist 32" Leg</a>
    </li>
    <li value="113">
        <a onclick="setDropdownText(113);">32x30 32" Waist 30" Leg</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To a `select` field:

```
<select>
    <option>30x30 30" Waist 30" Leg</option>
    <option>30x32 30" Waist 32" Leg</option>
    <option>32x30 32" Waist 30" Leg</option>
</select>
```

Via jQuery?

Comment: I would definitely use a text editor.

Comment: We don't do cookbook. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to change an HTML tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/apU5M/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly an odd requirement, but the easiest is probably by using [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
$('.sizeSelect').replaceWith(function() {
    var $select = $('<select>');

    $('li', this).each(function(item) {
        $select.append(new Option($(this).text(), $(this).attr('value')));
    });

    return $select;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/hinuh/2/)

Comment: You can create elements with jQuery pretty easily as well: `$("<option>", { text: $(this).text(), value: $(this).val() }).appendTo(select)`;

Comment: @JonathanSampson I prefer the constructor, shorter too ;-)