# Change tagname with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there away to change `<h4>text here</h4>` to a `<h1>text here</h1>`
I know how to add classes and change the style, but there is something in this code that has coded it to be a H4 when I want it to really be a H1

Comment: `in this code` what code. Show us this code.

Comment: You could use this solution found in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/918803/2229572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest method is to replace the `h4` element completely:

```
$('h4').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('<h1 />', { html: $(this).html() });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vr7zhshd/2/)

Comment: header elements may contain some other DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

A [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) solution:

```
function changeElementType(element, newtype) {
    var newelement = document.createElement(newtype);

    // move children
    while(element.firstChild) newelement.appendChild(element.firstChild);

    // copy attributes
    for( var i=0, a=element.attributes, l=a.length; i<l; i++) {
        newelement.attributes[a[i].name] = a[i].value;
    }

    // event handlers on children will be kept. Unfortunately, there is
    // no easy way to transfer event handlers on the element itself,
    // this would require a full management system for events, which is
    // beyond the scope of this answer. If you figure it out, do it here.

    element.parentNode.replaceChild(newelement, element);
}
```

You can now call, for instance:

```
changeElementType(document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0], "h1");
```

to change the first `<h4>` on the page into an `<h1>`.

Comment: this copies the element, but wipes its attributes when im using it.. can't see why though??

Answer (score 1):

A short vanilla-js solution

```js
var newEl = document.createElement('h1');
newEl.innerHTML = oldEl.innerHTML;
oldEl.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, oldEl);
```

Note this will destroy all event handlers and data added to `oldEl` or its descendants.

For a more complete solution, see [NiettheDarkAbsol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27404602/1529630).

Comment: `VanilaJS` is excelent :)

Comment: @vp_arth Agreed, but this nukes a lot of stuff ;)