# Expand HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to expand existing html tag?
For example i want add type of `<link>` tag and make some action on this type

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="new-type" href="theme.css">
```

and when we have link with new type make some action automatically?

Comment: If you can use jQuery then it would be very simple.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Comment: The best answer to this question will depend on what type of action you have in mind. For better answers, please describe your desired outcome in less abstract terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The best to do this is to use the [`data-` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). Those are skipped by any validator so safe to use for your own purpose:

```
<link id="someId" rel="stylesheet" type="new-type" href="theme.css" data-special="true">
```

If you use jQuery, you can even get it out easy:

```
var x = $("#someId").data("special");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `insertAdjacentHTML`. In the example below the new element will be inserted after the element defined by `getElementById("link"):

```
var element = document.getElementById("link");
var newElement = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="new-type" href="theme.css">'
element.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterend', newElement )
```

See this link for the full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you have to do a simple modification to your code like below-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" data-type="new-type" href="theme.css">
```