# Replace opening and closing HTML tags with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following markup:

```
<span style="font-size: 24px;"><font face="Courier New">[[code]]</font></span><br><p></p><span>{{name}}</span><span>[[otherCode]] </span>
```

and I'd need to replace the span only wrapping double brackets sequences. So in the case above I'd need to obtain:

```
<div style="font-size: 24px;"><font face="Courier New">[[code]]</font></div><br><p></p><span>{{name}}</span><div>[[otherCode]] </div>
```

(ie. the span surrounding {{name}} are not changed.

I know that regular expressions are usually not recommended but in this case I feel it's the only option I have. (FYI I do have jQuery and DOM access if you feel these would be better options.)

So far I've been trying with regex but can't seem to make it avoid the `{{}}` case. This is what I currently have:

```
/(<span[^>]*>(.*?\[\[\s*[^\]]+\s*\]\].*?)<\/span>)/gim
```

and I think that the solution goes towards stopping at the first span closing tag.

Comment: I'm feeling an answer with DOM, jQuery, and `.text()` coming....

Comment: Is regex mandatory? This can be achieved without regex

Comment: Wave of "you propably don't want to use regex" in 3… edit: oh! it's already here.

Comment: Thanks everyone :-) Well, I know regex isn't the best way but the HTML I get is generated and will always have the same structure as shown in the example. Basically, I'm getting this markup from a DB and then I'd need to modify it before inserting it to the DOM. As I do this client side using jQuery could well be an option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just want to avoid HTML with `{`s, you can use some variation on this regex:

```
<span[^>]*>[^{]*</span>
```

To ensure that there is a `[[  ]]` between the span, you can change the regex to this:

```
<span[^>]*>[^{]*?\[\[[^\]]*\]\][^{]*?</span>
```

Let me rewrite that with some spacing:

```
<span[^>]*>
   [^{]*?   \[\[   [^\]]*   \]\]   [^{]*?
</span>
```

(Note that you may have to escape the `/`.)

Since you want to replace the `span`s with `div`s, you can add capturing parenthesis like this:

```
<span([^>]*>[^{]*?\[\[[^\]]*\]\][^{]*?</)span>
```

Your replacement should be: `<div$1div>`.

This works when I test it online on your one sample, but it will fail if there are certain characters in the HTML. It might also break depending on the HTML structure, especially if it's poorly formed.

It might be easier to use a real parser in those cases. Alternatively, you might still be able to use the regex is you are able to break up the HTML and ensure that you are only passing chunks it can successfully work on.

Comment: Thanks. Your regex works better than mine. Problem though is that as you guessed this might not be very extensible. For example, "<span>Hello</span>" could become a possibility, and this regex doesn't work in this case. Ideally the regex should compare to the positive case (ie. match double brackets) but I'm afraid I can't find a regex for that. Anyway, I guess it'll be time to try out jQuery and see how to parse this.

Comment: @Dan I've added another regex to my answer. This one ensures that there are double brackets.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review this, it's greatly appreciated. Unfortunately the new regex has new problems on its own. For simplicity I've created a snippet here https://jsfiddle.net/2t5feexL/ showing the problem. See the incorrect replacement at the end of the string.

Comment: @Dan I forgot to make it lazy with `?`, but I fixed it. It should work better now.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really need to brush up my regex skills! This will be enough for now but I guess that I'll end up looking into proper html parsing as you suggested.