# How can I use jQuery to convert <div> into HTML table?

Tags: jquery, html, inky

```
<div> Hii,this is just an example  </div>
```

change to

```
<td>Hii, only tag will be change  </td>
```

Comment: Well, not really, a `<table>` has `<td>`'s and `<tr>`'s, and `<div>`'s have everything else! Are you asking this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag?

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific. A `<div>` can't exist in same location as  a `<td>` and vice versa . Read through [ask] then update question with proper details and html sample

Comment: The basic what i wanted to say is , the code written in <div> structure can be changed into <tr> ,<td>,<row>,<section>  etc or  (Inky grids). Once i found how to transforme the tags (<div> to HTML tags), thr rest thing will done by Inky which will convert comples table structure into simple HTML tags.

Answer (score 3):

HTML div structure to the table

```js
var div2table = $('.tr').map(function () {
                var issue = $(this);
                var tdline = issue.find('.td').map(function () {
                    return '<td>' + $(this).text();
                }).get().join('</td>');
                return '<tr>'  + tdline + '</td>';
            }).get().join('</tr>');
            
div2table = '<table border="1">' + div2table + '</tr></table>';
$('#table-container').html(div2table);
console.log(div2table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Div structure</p>
<div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
</div>
<div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
</div>
<div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
</div>
<p>After js execution, it will convert to Table</p>
<div id="table-container">

</div>
```

use the `div2table` variable to print your result

**Output**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>this will be 1st TD</td>
            <td>this will be 2nd TD</td>
            <td>this will be 3rd TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>this will be 1st TD</td>
            <td>this will be 2nd TD</td>
            <td>this will be 3rd TD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>this will be 1st TD</td>
            <td>this will be 2nd TD</td>
            <td>this will be 3rd TD</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For some reason, output is coming out as `<div class="tr">` instead of `<tr>`, and `<div class="td">` instead of `<td>`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

in case someone needs to convert on the-fly:

```
var div2table = $('.outer-div ').map(function () {
                var issue = $(this);
                var trline = issue.find('.inner-div').map(function () {
                    return '<td>' + $(this).text();
                }).get().join('</td>');
                return '<tr>'  + trline;
            }).get().join('</tr>');
```

`div2table = '<table>' + div2table + '</table>';`

where divs are

```
<div class='outer-div'><div class='inner-div'>this will be 1st TD</div>.....</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, output is coming out as `<div class="tr">` instead of `<tr>`, and `<div class="td">` instead of `<td>`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery to convert a `block` level element to `table-cell`:

```css
div{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div> Hii,this is just an example  </div>
<div> Hii,this is just an example  </div>
<div> Hii,this is just an example  </div>
<div> Hii,this is just an example  </div>
<div> Hii,this is just an example  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Roko

Comment: The basic what i wanted to say is , the code written in <div> structure can be changed into <tr> ,<td>,<row>,<section> etc or (Inky grids). Once i found how to transforme the tags (<div> to HTML tags), the rest thing will done by Inky which will convert comples table structure into simple HTML tags.