# How can I convert <div> tags to <tr> and <td> tags using a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am attempting to follow @ishtiaq-ahmed's and @yob's answer to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007998/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-convert-div-into-html-table/42397635) about converting `<div>` tags to `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. However, the output does not actually display what the function is meant to do, and instead the `<div>` classes remain as `<div>`classes. The code is as follows:

```js
var div2table = $('.tr').map(function() {
  var issue = $(this);
  var tdline = issue.find('.td').map(function() {
    return '<td>' + $(this).text();
  }).get().join('</td>');
  return '<tr>' + tdline + '</td>';
}).get().join('</tr>');

div2table = '<table>' + div2table + '</tr></table>';

console.log(div2table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tr'>
  <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
  <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
  <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
</div>
<div class='tr'>
  <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
  <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
  <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
</div>
<div class='tr'>
  <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
  <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
  <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
</div>
```

Is there some way to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `console.log(div2table);` outputs the converted HTML - when you state "*the output does not actually display what the function is meant to do*" - do you mean you want to *replace* the divs with `div2table`?  Something like `$(document).html(div2table)`?  (would be better if it was wrapped)

Comment: Sorry if this a dumb question, but where would I find `console.log(div2table)`? I'm more looking for the latter option but am interested in exploring what you referenced in the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm brand new to jQuery. I know the DOM method is in the code but where do I find its printed output if not in the console? The output seems to look just like the HTML that @ishtiaq-ahmed wrote

Comment: Ah, where do you find the console *output* - phew, that makes more sense - press F12 in your browser and it will be in the console.  In a SO snippet, it appears at the bottom of the output window and in a jsfiddle it appears either in the output or in the browser console depending on your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a container around your elements for ease of access and just replaced it's content with the output of the function

```js
var div2table = $('.container .tr').map(function() {
  var issue = $(this);
  var tdline = issue.find('.td').map(function() {
    return '<td>' + $(this).text();
  }).get().join('</td>');
  return '<tr>' + tdline + '</td>';
}).get().join('</tr>');

div2table = '<table>' + div2table + '</tr></table>';

$('.container').html(div2table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'>this will be 1st TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 2nd TD</div>
    <div class='td'>this will be 3rd TD</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense. One question (from a beginner): Is it standard practice to separate two classes in a jQuery selector with a space rather than by comma?

Comment: you might want to read up on jquery selectors, more specifically for this case: https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I guess the space is kind of like a `>` in CSS then, in that it defines a child/grandchild/etc.

Comment: `a b` space selector is like `$("a").find("b")` while `a>b` is like `$(a).children().filter(b)`.  *The space selector in jquery is the same as the space selector in css*